# Сортировка всех столбцов по убыванию DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Таблица заполняется рандомные цифрами и по нажатии на кнопку все столбцы должны быть отсортированы по убыванию. Попробовал написать вот такой код, но он что-то не работает.
М - Размер таблицы.

```
for(int i =0; i < M; i++)
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[i], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: Работайте с массивом, а не с контролем, после того как выполните нулевые действия в массиве, просто обновите содержимое контрола.

Comment: Можно немного подробнее? Как перейти от таблицы к массиву?

Comment: У вас изначально должен быть массив, а не таблица

Comment: Про сортировке одного столбца порядок данных в других столбцах нарушается.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dataGridView1.ItemsSource.ToList().OrderByDescending(v => v);



public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var T = new List<Number>();
            var rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                T.Add(new Number{ Num = rnd.Next(0, 100) });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = T.OrderByDescending(v => v.Num).ToList();
        }

    }

    class Number
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
    }
```

обновил ответ. вот атк работает 100 проц проверял

Comment: Не работает Items.Source. Я заполняю массив случайно вот так: for (int x = 0; x < M; x++) for (int y = 0; y < M; y++) { int s; s = (rnd.Next(0,100)); dataGridView1[x, y].Value = s; }